# Get custom field value but hide first 19 and last 2 characters

Tags: wordpress, get, hide, dashboard, custom-fields

Geeks and code Gods,

I am having an issue with my wordpress code. I have added 3 extra columns to the dashboard's pages screen.

One of which displays the custom field `'scode'`. The scode custom field holds the cart66 shortcode which adds an 'add cart' button to the page it is assigned to.

The shortcode looks like this:

```
[add_to_cart item="HD-NL-7010"]
```

Each page has a different shortcode.
Every shortcode is the same length, 31 characters long.

However Id prefer not to show the whole shortcode in the column, only the product code `*HD-NL-7010*` section of the code.

Is it possible to hide the first 19 and last 2 characters. Basically removing `[add_to_cart item="   and   "]`

Below is the code I added to function.php to add the custom columns to the pages table:

```
function test_modify_post_table( $column ) {
    $column['scode'] = 'Product Code';
    $column['Price'] = 'Price';
    $column['Product_Image'] = 'Image';
    return $column;
}

add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns', 'test_modify_post_table' );


function test_modify_post_table_row( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $post_id );

    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'scode' :
            echo $custom_fields['scode'][0];
            break;


        case 'Price' :
            echo '£' . $custom_fields['Price'][0];
            break;


        case 'Product_Image' :
            echo $custom_fields['Product_Image'][0];
            break;

        default:
    }
}

add_filter( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'test_modify_post_table_row', 10, 2 );
```

Thank you for reading this post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm going to ask this in another post but does anyone know how to get the Product_Image to show as an image in the page column rather than the image attachment ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding, does PHP's [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) help?  Something like:

```
case 'scode' :
    echo substr( $custom_fields['scode'][0], 19, 10 );
    break;
```

For what it's worth, I think I'd store just the code (HD-NL-7010) in the custom field, rather than the shortcode code, then apply the shortcode where needed (with [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)).

Comment: That works great thanks. But I will certainly use the do_shortcode instead. That looks like a much better way of doing it.
Thanks again.